# Pandas set value of one field based on value in another field using numpy.where

Tags: pandas, numpy

I am trying to set the value of 1 column based on value in another column in pandas:

```
df['col1']=pd.Series(np.where(df['col0'] == 'Test', 1,0))
```

I get an output like:

```
col0     col1
 Test     NaN
```

If I check:
`df['col0'].unique()`--I get: Test

So I expect:

```
col0     col1
 Test     1
```

or at least:

```
col0     col1
 Test     0
```

Why am I getting:

```
col0     col1
 Test     NaN
```

Comment: Show the originial series, so we can test it.  For binary classifications like this, you shouldn't need `np.where`, `df['col0'].eq('Test').astype(int)` should work

Comment: I solved it...the pd.Series is unnecessary

Comment: if you want to understand the underlying error, look up index alignment.  That's what's causing the `NaN`.  Since you are assigning a new series, and the index doesn't match, it fills with `NaN`